# Provisioning profile Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm new on iOs development and I'm facing this issue:

[image]

I found some posts about but nothing work out.

Comment: after creating certificates have you download and install certificates?

Comment: I didn't create the certificates.

Comment: Then first follow @Neha Gupta answer

Comment: and for temporary use you can change "Code sign identity" in build setting with "Don't code signing" option

Comment: change bundle identifier to some unique one and this error will disappear. It says that current bundle identifier is not a unique.

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to create signing certificate, then register your app bundle identifier, later need to create provisioning profile with your bundle identifier.

For each and every step details, see below link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

Comment: I'm on apple developer account, and the message is this: "Purchase your membership.
To continue your enrollment, complete your purchase now."

Comment: Well that is pretty clear... You need to complete your enrollment.

Comment: Can I create the provisioning profile whithout complete the enrollment?

Answer (score 0):

Another developer account already has the `com.br.well.MackResolve` app ID registered.  If you are working with the original developer of this app, have them add your apple developer account to their team so you can use their code signing identity.  If not, you will need to change the app's bundle ID to a unique identifier not already reserved by another developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Change the bundle Id as explained, its already taken by someone on Developer/Enterprise Account under apple.

1. If this is not a solution ask the previous vendor/authority who was
   holding this app to give you the P12, and provisioning profile for 
   this Bundle Id to regenerate and use to build new IPA.
2. If this app now is taken over by your side or company and not yet uploaded to store make a new bundle ID
3. If this is also not possible change the bundle Id for the tell the previous holding authority to delete the app ID. / Transfer the itunesConnect App to your developer account and resubmit the new IPA with updated profiles. This will allow you to overwrite the existing apps on users side rather having duplicates.